# Why the icon is not displayed in the web page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a HTML like the below,

```
<div id ="div1">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="success">
           <i class="" id="successIcon"></i>
          // I need to add the text Success here
      </a>
</div>
```

In Js

```
Var divId  = document.getElementById('div1');
$(divId).find('#success').append("Success"); // Appends everytime "Success" when the PAge is loaded.
```

Even If I try using,

```
$(divId).find('#success').text("Success"); 
$(divId ) .find("#successIcon").attr("class", "fa fa-success text-success");
// The icon "Success" is not appended to the front of the text "Success", if I use text().
```

I need the `Text` as well as the `Icon` infront of the text.

Could anyone please help?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `getElementById()` to use as jQuery selector, just do `$("#div1")` . Note that id's need to be unique for the page.

Comment: `$("#successIcon").attr("class", "fa fa-check text-success")` - there is no success icon and we assume your IDs are unique as they should be

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to use find. You can just use a selector on in `$()`.

So you can use:

```
$('#success').append("Success");
$('#success #successIcon').attr("class", "fa fa-success text-success")
```

Or since you use id's (which should be unique) you can use:

```
$('#success').append("Success");
$('#successIcon').attr("class", "fa fa-success text-success")
```

Comment: I see, append should work in that case.

Comment: Also success is not an icon in fontawesome

Answer (score -1):

Try this.i think this is what you are trying to do.

```js
$('#div1 .dropdown-item').append('Success Message here');
$('#div1 .dropdown-item #successIcon').attr('class', 'fa fa-success text-success');
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id ="div1">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="success">
               <i class="" id="successIcon"></i>
              
          </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As presented in your question, your code does work (see snippet below)

But there are several things you're not doing tidily:

- use `const`/`let`, not var anymore
- use jquery selectors instead of `document.getElementById`. That's the power of jQuery
- `fa-success` does not exist in font awesome. You can use `fa-ckeck` instead

```js
//Your original code. Just corrected case fo "var" and used "fa-check"
var divId = document.getElementById('div1');
$(divId).find('#success').append("Success"); 
$(divId).find("#successIcon").attr("class", "fa fa-check text-success");

// How you should have written it
const div2 = $('#div2');
div2.find('#success').append("Success");
div2.find('#successIcon').addClass("fa fa-check text-success");
```

```html
<!--This is frameworks inclusion -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.1/css/font-awesome.css" />

<!--This is your original html, minus the faulty comment-->
<div id ="div1">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="success">
           <i class="" id="successIcon"></i>
      </a>
</div>

<!--This is for second example-->
<div id ="div2">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="success">
           <i class="" id="successIcon"></i>
      </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Except `const div2 = $('#div2');
div2.find` is a waste of time

Comment: @mplungian took me a while to write and test, and answers popped in during the time. However declaring the const is not a waste of time as it is used twice, and it avoids jQuery doing the query for `#div2` twice, which can become a major hit on performance when repeated again and again on a lengthy DOM.

Comment: And no one else has pointed out the original code does work

Comment: You will NEVER need to find an element by ID inside another element by ID - you can replace `const div2 = $('#div2'); div2.find` by `$`

Comment: Well maybe if you've written the entire HTML, but as discouraged as it is, it does exist, and can even become useful when your page is composed of code from different sources. Very common for instance when working with WordPress plugins and themes from different sources to have different elements with id `#content`or such....

Comment: If you say so. I deleted my answer and made it a comment